# Download multiple files in queue with AFDownloadRequestOperation

Tags: ios, download, background-image, afnetworking

I'm using AFDownloadRequestOperation + AFNetworking to download and resume a list of files from a server. The code is working great at downloading and resuming multiple files at a time. But how to queue all operations inside an operations queue and execute the operation one by one?

Here's my current code

```
// request the video file from server
NSString *downloadURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [recipe download_url], [step valueForKey:@"video"]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadURL]];
AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request targetPath:videoFile shouldResume:YES];

// done saving!
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"Done downloading %@", videoFile);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %ld", (long)[error code]);
}];

// set the progress
[operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation, NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {
     float progress = ((float)totalBytesReadForFile) / totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile;
     [progressBar setProgress:progress];
}];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to add the operations to AFHTTPClient's operationQueue, or add them to a NSOperationQueue you've made yourself.

Then set the number of maximum concurrent operations for the queue your using to 1

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[operation start];
```

to

```
[[YourAFHTTPClientSubclass sharedInstance] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

By default, this will have a maximum number of operations "determined dynamically by the NSOperationQueue object based on current system conditions".

If you really want to force everything to one at a time, do:

```
[YourAFHTTPClientSubclass sharedInstance].operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

This will block all network operations until the operation is finished.

Of course, you can make your own operation queue as Audun suggested, but it's probably better to let the system decide what to do based on current conditions.

Depending on your use case, you may want to set the priority of the operations of the video downloads to low:

```
operation.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityLow
```

This will allow other network operations to be placed in the queue at a higher priority than your video downloads.